# How can i match a markdown list text block via javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

Hey Stack Overflow members,
I am trying to parse this text and get two **separate** matches, the unordered markdown list blocks. The problem is that i cannot figure out a way to match them. **There maybe text after them.**

I am using **JavaScript flavored regex**.

This is what i have been trying, **full example**: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/brjENQ/3)

```
(\*|\t\*|\s+\*).*
```

List:

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
    * Item 2a
    * Item 2b

* Item 1
* Item 2
    * Item 2a
    * Item 2b
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s\S]` will make JavaScript multiline, since dot `.` doesn't do multiline.

`[\s\S]` will search for every whitespace and non-whitespace character including newline characters.

```js
var match = document.querySelector("pre").textContent.match(/(\*|\t\*|\s+\*)[\s\S]*?\n\n/g);

console.log(match);
```

```html
<pre>

When there is text preceding the block

* Item 1
* Item 2
    * Item 2a
    * Item 2b

* Item 1
* Item 2
    * Item 2a
    * Item 2b
    
When there is more text in the block
</pre>
```

Another method. Use the global flag `g` for your `match`.

```js
var match = document.querySelector("pre").textContent.match(/(\*|\t\*|\s+\*).*/g);

//raw match
console.log(match);

//with trim
match_trim = match.map(function(element){
    return (element.trim());
});

console.log(match_trim);

//with join
match_join = match.join("");

console.log(match_join);
```

```html
<pre>
* Item 1
* Item 2
    * Item 2a
    * Item 2b

* Item 1
* Item 2
    * Item 2a
    * Item 2b
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer the problem is that i want to match the groups separately, i am sorry if i was unclear updated example -> https://regex101.com/r/brjENQ/3

Comment: Well also update your question, because my solution is the answer to your question on this page. The following will definitely solve it: `(\*|\t\*|\s+\*)[\s\S]*?\n\n`. I advise method two though, for more control.

Comment: I checked your second method, and it will partially work , just need to remove the top white space. I think i can get it to work from here Thanks